# Kubernetes with flannel cannot establish connection between 2 pods on different nodes

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

We have started a cluser with /16 subnet, and flannel as our networking overlay. The pods are getting created on the 2 nodes running sock-shop demo application. But what we are noticing is that pods in different nodes cannot establish connection between them. We do see the routing entries for the pods using flannel.1 interface. Even ping fails. Any pointers to debug information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if the docker bridge ip (--bip= option) is in the same network as flannel interface.
Also you can check ETCD network settings in /coreos.com/network/ with etcdctl command.